# Setup vitual environment and install lxml package

Tags: python, lxml, modulenotfounderror, virtual-environment

I have Python 2.7 virtual environment setup where I am trying to install lxml.
Even after the installation, it gave me the error for 'module not found', so I installed lxml 4.6.3 figuring the one originally installed was 3.2.1, an older version and not compatible with python 2.7.
I was able to uninstall 4.6.3 but the 3.2.1 version , so I manually deleted the files and tried reinstalling the 4.6.3 version. That did not seem to have helped and I may have messed up the environment. I am now getting the error 'attempted relative import beyond top-level package' when trying to reinstall 4.6.3 version.
Now, I am trying to setup the environment once again and I get the error 'no module named venv' when I try to execute 'python -m venv TestEnv'.

I don't think any one has run into this kind of issue, but any help in setting up the environment and installing the lxml module will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.